# Wi-fi doesn't work on Xubuntu 22.04 installation but works on Live USB

Tags: wireless, 22.04, xubuntu

I have a Live USB with Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and Wi-Fi works fine there. I installed Xubuntu from this Live USB to the hard drive and booted from the hard drive, but now I can't connect to Wi-Fi.

Everything is fine with the Wi-Fi router. I am now using the Internet from the router on my phone. The password I entered is exactly correct. I did NOT change any settings, that is, the settings are the same as on Live USB.

My system is a Lenovo X121e with AMD E-450 and SSD memory.

What shall I do?

Comment: You need to include a minimum of what type of WiFi card you are using with Ubuntu and any error messages you can find. Then someone might be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this. The issue was the security settings of my router. Switching to WPA3 Personal manually worked.